# How can I tell PyCharm to not send node_modules to git repo?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

PyCharm version 2018.2

No matter what I try, PyCharm still sends `node_modules` to the git repo.

I want to make a universal exclusion, so that no matter what level of the directory tree, `node_modules` is excluded from git, but it just doesn't work.

You can see here I have tried every combination to specify.

[image]

But when I select "commit directory", you can see from the next screenshot below that it still wants to send all the `node_modules` files.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It appears that it is better to use gitingore, maybe a global one, than the builtin Ignore list.

And by the way, it is only possible to ignore unversioned files, and if files are already in the added status, as on the screenshot, you need to revert them first to become unversioned.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `node_modules` from index

> The index is a single, large, binary file in /.git/index,
>   which lists all files in the current branch, their sha1 checksums,
>   time stamps and the file name -- it is not another directory with a
>   copy of files in it. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

```
git rm -r --cached node_modules
```

2. (optional) if node_modules doesn't exist yet on .gitignore make sure to add it there (right relative path to git project root)
3. Add changes (without the node_modules) to index and commit

   git add . 
   git commit -am "Remove previously tracked node_modules"